# Java temp files and automated deletion

Tags: java, file, io, temp

**It is safe to use java's *createTempFile* method to create a temp file and then rename it and keep it as a permanent file?** Or does java or the system in some way keep track of its temporary files and delete them at some point?

btw..this is related to Mac OS X specifically.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you call the [deleteOnExit()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) method on the file object, it will remain after the application terminates.

It is best however to create the file on your directory and not in the default directory (usually /tmp) which may be erased by the OS.

Comment: sorry one thing i forgot to mention, when i rename the temp file I am moving it to the users home directory.

Comment: In this case, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article on when OSX cleansup the temporary file folders:

http://www.xvsxp.com/system/system_tools_cleanup.php

I wouldn't rely on the temporary file folder as a permanent place to store files...